# Rails 4 Nested Form "Unpermitted Parameters" Not Answered Anywhere Else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, nested-forms, nested-attributes

My nested form is not working properly no matter what I try and I searched all the StackExchange's for a solution to this seemingly easy problem. This is where I am right now to get it to work at show up in the view at all.

The form is using the Event controller create action from a non-restful location, hence the global variable (a pages controller, with a specific page, where the form is generated). My ticket model gets generated when the nested form is submitted, and the Event ID gets passed, but it doesn't fill in the "Name" field for the ticket model because it says "Unpermitted Parameters: Ticket." But they're defined as whitelisted in the Events controller! Argh! I'm thinking something is wrong with the form, but nothing I try seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

*** UPDATED CODE THAT IS NOW WORKING ***

Form.html.erb:

```
<div class="form-inputs">
 <%= simple_form_for @event, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <%= f.input :name, class: "control-label" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tickets do |ticket| %>
     <%= ticket.input :name %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
   <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                launchpad_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Event_Controller.rb

```
def new (this is totally skipped and unnecessary)
  @event = Event.new
  @ticket = @event.tickets.build
end    

def create
  @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @event.save
    format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Your event was created.' }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
   end
 end
end

def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, tickets_attributes: [ :name, :id, :event_id, :_destroy ])
end
```

Pages_Controller.rb (where the form originate

```
 def new
  @event = Event.new
  @ticket = @event.tickets.build
 end
```

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Database Relationships
    has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :events do
 resources :tickets
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just, remove from create action this line:

```
@ticket = @event.tickets.build(event_params[:ticket_attributes])
```

And, change your event_params:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, :main_event_image, tickets_attributes: [:id, :name, :cost, :event_id, :registration_id, :created_at])
end
```

Te field name must be: `tickets_attributes: [ ...` (tickets in plural). I think this do the trick.

**Edit**: I'm agree with @smathy, if no fix to `f.simple_fields_for :tickets ...` it can't work.

Your new method must look like this:

```
def new
  @new_event = Event.new
  @new_event.tickets.build
end
```

I'm a fan of standards, and I prefer use `@event` instead of `@new_event` as in your form (it's part of convention over configuration on rails)

Comment: That's where I started, but no dice. Still doesn't pass the data.

Comment: I'm sure: you must use you must use ```tickets_attributes: ``` and not ```ticket_attributes``` at the method ```event_params```.

Comment: I definitely use the tickets_attributes. But why would this nested form not work? Is there a database relation problem?

Comment: Did you fix also ```f.simple_fields_for :tickets```?

Comment: If I do this: <%= f.simple_fields_for :tickets, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }  do |ticket| %>, the nested form does not appear.

Comment: You're right, and I use the convention nearly everywhere. The 'new_event' here is because I have the 'event' doing something else on the page. I'm sure there's a better way, but I'm just trying to get the MVP launched for now, know what I mean?

Comment: Did it fix your issue?

Comment: Convention regarding, it's ok. Also many times you'll find something like ```current_x``` (event, user, project ...) as a workaround for this cases.

Comment: Nope, issue still exists. I added the HTML form to the ticket for review per request.

Comment: Ok, nothing rendered for tickets. Can you add your EventController new action to the question? Tks

Comment: The 'New' action never gets called. It only calls the 'create' action.

Comment: The create action receives the form filled. I ask for the action that submit the form (the standard RESTful is ```new```).

Comment: I used pry and it never ran the New action at any point. Maybe that is part of the issue? I updated the controller above.

Comment: Ok, but, must be an action that send the empty form to the browser. That action must create ```@new_event``` and must do ```@new_event.tickets.build```.  The url of the new empty form must show it's name.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the information from Alejandro (which is correct), you also have `f.simple_fields_for @ticket, ...` whereas you should have `f.simple_fields_for :tickets, ...`

If you check your `log/development.log` for the `Processing by EventsController#create` the line after will be a `Parameters:` line, you'll see that the parameters that have been sent through are under a `:ticket` key instead of a `:tickets_attributes` key because of the `fields_for` error.

Fix that, and the `permit` line and you should be fine.

#### Update

Hopefully you realized that you also don't need the `@ticket = @event.tickets.build(event_params[:ticket_attributes])` line at all once that `fields_for` is fixed too. The setting of all the associated `tickets` is all done via the `Event` object thanks to the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` helper.

Comment: If I change it to :tickets, which I tried, it doesn't show the nested form at all. However, if I use :ticket it does. Checking the server log, I get this: Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"snNF/cfnYKjoyE8gF3iDJjTvLzqGsdwgVSIAov1LH/8=", "event"=>{"name"=>"This is test event Number 2", "starts_at(1i)"=>"2015", "starts_at(2i)"=>"3", "starts_at(3i)"=>"20", "starts_at(4i)"=>"03", "starts_at(5i)"=>"03", "ends_at(1i)"=>"2015", "ends_at(2i)"=>"3", "ends_at(3i)"=>"20", "ends_at(4i)"=>"03", "ends_at(5i)"=>"03",

Comment: "description"=>"df gfsdgdfgdfsngdsfjkngkljshjgklfjksfdgkjfghlkjsf lsdgsd","ticket"=>{"name"=>"Ticket 1", "cost"=>"15"}}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: ticket
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "events"

Comment: At this point I'd ensure you restarted `spring` and your server: `spring stop` to restart spring, and quit and restart your `rails server` - because how I've described it, based on your associations and your `anaf` is the right way to have it. Do these restarts, try again, and if you're still having problems paste the HTML generated by the form (just one ticket please :) into your question too (not in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at the same problem like crazy and at the end I was able to  fix it...  Try placing the binding.pry in the first line of create method and print the event_params hash and check if you see ticket_attributes hash inside of it ... That's when it ll throw unpermitted parameter ... And I see event has_many tickets , so I am guessing ticket_attributes needs to be pluralized to be tickets_attributes